placeholder property for the select is not working when i bind the dynamic data to the select dropdown
<div class="control">
  <label for="boardName">Select Board</label>
  <select name="boardName" id="boardName" formControlName="boardName"
          class="form-select form-select-md mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
          (change)="onBoardSelectionChange($event)">
    <option disabled selected>select board</option>
    <option *ngFor="let board of boardsAllData" value="{{ board.id }}">
      {{ board.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div class="errorMsg" *ngIf=" addQuestonsForm.get('boardName')?.touched &&
    addQuestonsForm.get('boardName')?.invalid ">
    <p class="error">please select board</p>
  </div>
</div>

here I want to display the placeholder for the dropdown , but when i
bind the data with ngFor then why placeholder is not displaying and
when I remove the ngFor and bind static data then placeholder is
displaying

Try giving value attribute of disabled (default) option a null value i.e. value="null"

Try this
<option [defaultSelected]="">select board</option> <- change this
<option *ngFor="let board of boardsAllData" [value]="board.id"> <- and this
